# GWT layout with multiple resizable datagrids

Tags: css, gwt, layout

]We have a screen containing 4 `datagrid`. We are able to align them using a `grid` and combination of *Vertical Panel* and *Horizontal Panel*. `Grid(2,2)` holds all 4 `datagrids`.Everything is fine But when the Window is resized, `grids` don't re-size even if `.setSize("100%","100%")` is set. We find that the problem is we are using *Vertical Panel* which does not implement Provides *Resize/Requires* Resize. 
Could you please suggest alternative layout strategy.

Comment: Provide your sample code to work around please...

Answer (score 0):

There are still two solutions:

- Create your own `HorizontalPanel`/`VerticalPanel` and implement the interfaces `RequireResize` and `ProvidesResize`
- use a `SimpleLayoutPanel` and `CSS`.